# Missing top and bottom panels in ubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04

I'm missing top and bottom panels in Natty.  Googling for this the most common resolution is:

```
a@omnipresent ~ % gconftool-2 --shutdown
a@omnipresent ~ % rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/panel     
a@omnipresent ~ % pkill gnome-panel
```

However, this is not helping me. It does not bring the top and bottom panels back.

Is there something else that I should be trying?

**Update**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 11.04
Release:    11.04
Codename:   natty
```

Comment: Unity doesn't provide an additional panel. You can use an old gnome-panel.

Comment: @Marco how do I do that?

Comment: @Achu I've updated the question with my release info.

Comment: <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> insert gnome-panel

Comment: `gnome-panel &` works but I have to run that everytime I boot. I'll have to add it to my boot scripts. thanks

Comment: @Omnipresent: we're more interested in what **desktop environment** you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was default Panel restore script Writen by PhrankDaChicken. You can find the full article from this -> [blog](http://bithacker.blogspot.com/2010/05/restore-default-gnome-panels-in-ubuntu.html)

To use the PanelRestore script:

1. Download this [PanelRestore.tar.gz](http://www.starryhope.com/downloads/PanelRestore.tar.gz)
2. Extract it and run it by double clicking.
   It will ask you what do you want to do dialbox like this:

[image]

Select "Restore default panel setting"

Never tested but hope it will help :)